# Azure Data Factory v2: fail to create copy activity via c# code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

The issue that my inner copy activity from foreach activity isn't published to ADF. I don't see that activity in ADF UI and even after I add it manually I not able not debug, publish and even view activity code =(

When I click on publish I see error 'Publishing: Got error while publishing'
When I'm trying to debug:

```
Failed
{"__zone_symbol__currentTask":{"type":"microTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"Promise.then","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0}}
```

Clicking on 'Code' button doesn't do any actions.

Anything I missing? Should I add copy activity somewhere else?

Foreach/copy activity in c# code is following :

```
private Activity CreateDocumentIteratorActivity(
        string lookupDocumentsActivityName,
        string sourceDatasetName,
        string destinationDatasetName,
        string logsServiceName)
    {
        return new ForEachActivity()
        {
            Name = "ForEachDocument",
            IsSequential = false,
            BatchCount = BackupSettings.Value.ParallelThreads,
            Items = new Expression { Value = "@activity('" + lookupDocumentsActivityName + "').output.value" },
            DependsOn = new List<ActivityDependency>() {
                new ActivityDependency() {
                    Activity = lookupDocumentsActivityName,
                    DependencyConditions = new List<string>() {
                        DependencyCondition.Succeeded
                    }
                }
            },
            Activities = new[] {
                CreateCopyDocToFileActivity(sourceDatasetName, destinationDatasetName, logsServiceName, BackupSettings.Value.BackupLogsFolder)
            }
        };
    }

private CopyActivity CreateCopyDocToFileActivity(string sourceDatasetName, string destinationDatasetName, string logsServiceName, string logsPath)
    {
        return new CopyActivity()
        {
            Name = "CopyDocToFile",
            Policy = new ActivityPolicy()
            {
                Retry = BackupSettings.Value.RetryPolicyConfiguration.RetryCount,
                RetryIntervalInSeconds = (int)BackupSettings.Value.RetryPolicyConfiguration.DeltaBackOff.TotalSeconds,
                Timeout = BackupSettings.Value.RetryPolicyConfiguration.MaxBackOff
            },
            Source = new DocumentDbCollectionSource()
            {
                Query = new Expression(@"select value c from c where c.id = '@{item().id}'")
            },
            Inputs = new[] { new DatasetReference() {
                ReferenceName = sourceDatasetName,
                Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "collectionName", new Expression("@pipeline().parameters.collectionName") }
                }
            }},
            Outputs = new[] { new DatasetReference() {
                ReferenceName = destinationDatasetName,
                Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                     { "fileName", new Expression("@concat(pipeline().parameters.collectionName,  '/', item().PartitionKey, '/', item().id)") },
                     { "backupDateStr", new Expression("@pipeline().TriggerTime") }
                }
            }},
            Sink = new BlobSink()
            {
                CopyBehavior = CopyBehaviorType.PreserveHierarchy,
            },

            ParallelCopies = BackupSettings.Value.ParallelThreads,
            EnableSkipIncompatibleRow = true,
            RedirectIncompatibleRowSettings = new RedirectIncompatibleRowSettings()
            {
                LinkedServiceName = logsServiceName,
                Path = logsPath
            }
        };
    }
```

Response from /pipelines api call:

```
{
"value": [
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/d2259601-012b-4253-895b-02916ef0f7f7/resourceGroups/Test-Data/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/backup-data-factory/pipelines/cosmosBackup",
    "name": "cosmosBackup",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
    "properties":
    {
        "activities": [
        {
            "type": "Lookup",
            "typeProperties":
            {
                "source":
                {
                    "type": "DocumentDbCollectionSource",
                    "query":
                    {
                        "value": "select root.id, root.PartitionKey from root",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                },
                "dataset":
                {
                    "referenceName": "source_cosmosdb_collection",
                    "parameters":
                    {
                        "collectionName": "@pipeline().parameters.collectionName"
                    },
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "firstRowOnly": false
            },
            "policy":
            {
                "timeout": "02:00:00",
                "retry": 3,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30
            },
            "name": "GetDocumentsIds"
        },
        {
            "type": "ForEach",
            "typeProperties":
            {
                "isSequential": false,
                "batchCount": 4,
                "items":
                {
                    "value": "@activity('GetDocumentsIds').output.value",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "activities": [
                {
                    "type": "Copy",
                    "typeProperties":
                    {
                        "source":
                        {
                            "type": "DocumentDbCollectionSource",
                            "query":
                            {
                                "value": "select value c from c where c.id = '@{item().id}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        },
                        "sink":
                        {
                            "type": "BlobSink",
                            "copyBehavior": "PreserveHierarchy"
                        },
                        "parallelCopies": 4,
                        "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true,
                        "redirectIncompatibleRowSettings":
                        {
                            "linkedServiceName": "destination_cosmosdb_collection_service",
                            "path": "backup/logs"
                        }
                    },
                    "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "source_cosmosdb_collection",
                        "parameters":
                        {
                            "collectionName":
                            {
                                "value": "@pipeline().parameters.collectionName",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }],
                    "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "destination_cosmosdb_collection",
                        "parameters":
                        {
                            "fileName":
                            {
                                "value": "@concat(pipeline().parameters.collectionName,  '/', item().PartitionKey, '/', item().id)",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "backupDateStr":
                            {
                                "value": "@pipeline().TriggerTime",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }],
                    "policy":
                    {
                        "timeout": "02:00:00",
                        "retry": 3,
                        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30
                    },
                    "name": "CopyDocToFile"
                }]
            },
            "name": "ForEachDocument",
            "dependsOn": [
            {
                "activity": "GetDocumentsIds",
                "dependencyConditions": ["Succeeded"]
            }]
        }],
        "parameters":
        {
            "collectionName":
            {
                "type": "String"
            }
        }
    },
    "etag": "01006ed4-0000-0000-0000-5b3b38450000"
}]
}
```

Comment: Could you press F2, and then click refresh button, and then get the response of list pipelines api in network tab? Could you share the json of that pipeline in the response?

Looks like there are something which is not recognized by UI.

Comment: Updated question. Thanks for helping trick, didn't though about that way of viewing pipeline code =)

Comment: Your pipeline json looks good. You mean, when double click the foreach acivity, you didn’t see the copy activity? Is there any error in console when double click the foreach activity?

Comment: And does your dataset shown out successfully?

Comment: click on foreach activity works fine and opens actually this activity but it's empty. Also I see zero inner activities when looking on description of foreach activity. here's sceenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/uLoojzKz5zN

Comment: Datasets code seems ok: I can view it and can change/publish without errors

Comment: If I try to add manually same copy activity in UI - I see it in UI, but still can't view code and publish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue. This part is not right.

```
 "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true,
  "redirectIncompatibleRowSettings": {
      "linkedServiceName": "destination_cosmosdb_collection_service",
          "path": "backup/logs"
}
```

It shoud be

```
 "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true,
   "redirectIncompatibleRowSettings": {
                 "linkedServiceName": {
                   "referenceName": "destination_cosmosdb_collection_service",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
         },
   "path": "backup/logs"
                            },
```